# How to copy Image file to other folder using ember cli?

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

My template upload

```
{{input type="file" value=files}}
<button {{action 'upload'}}>Upload</button>
```

my Controller upload

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Controller.extend({
actions:{
    upload:function(){
        alert(this.get('files'));
        //getting upload file address 
    }

}
});
```

how to copy it to other loaction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't upload without a specific server-side implementation. Ember runs only in the browser, the browser performs the upload, the server has to handle the upload. Also, what information may be available from a file input may be limited by the browser.